# Query name with the latest date

Tags: sql

I am struggling with sql command to query data I need and would like some help.
Let’s say we have data in the db like:

```
Joe    101   2014-02-01
Max   102  2014-04-02
Joe    102  2015-01-01
Am    103   2012-01-04
Joe    103   2015-05-05
Am    103   2014-02-02
Tom   103  2015-01-01
```

I would like to get the result as (no order). basically get the latest of Am, Max, and Joe  (not Tom)

```
Am  103  2014-02-02
Max 102  2014-04-02
Joe  103  2015-05-05
```

Comment: And why not Tom?  Something against him?

Comment: Please label your question with the SQL type you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL:

```
SELECT name, id, date
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, MAX(date) AS date
    FROM table
    GROUP BY name
) t2
ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.date = t2.date
WHERE t1.name = 'Am' OR t1.name = 'Max' OR t1.name = 'Joe'
```

The inner query finds the latest date for each name, and this result is then `JOIN`ed against the table to obtain the other information.

As @GordonLinoff pointed out, this bias against Tom needs to be explained.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general SQL version. Not sure on your business rule and whether it's safe to take the `MAX` of the numeric value, but if so, the query is pretty simple.

```
SELECT
    Name,
    MAX(Id) AS Id,
    MAX([Date]) AS [Date]
FROM [table]
WHERE Name <> 'Tom' -- Either exclude Tom or include others
-- WHERE Name IN ('Am', 'Max', 'Joe')
GROUP BY Name
```

If it isn't safe to do the max of id and date fields, then you may want to look into the syntax of an equivalent ROW_NUMBER function for your database system:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Id,
    [Date]
FROM (
    SELECT
        Name,
        Id,
        [Date],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name
            ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM [table]
    WHERE Name <> 'Tom' -- Either exclude Tom or include others
    -- WHERE Name IN ('Am', 'Max', 'Joe')
    ) T
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: @sithathai - Please feel free to upvote an answer if it helped you and accept it if it solved your question. This helps others to know which answers may have helped and if any solved your question. It also increases your reputation.